# Show very big double values on EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, decimalformat

First of all please excuse me for my bad English speaking.

I am new to Android Development. I have a problem and think you can solve it.

The problem is:

I have a very big double value like `12345678987654321` in my android app
but when i want to show it on `EditText`, it will be shown like this `12345678987654300`.
In this case when my value characters is over than **15 chars** android shows remaining chars **with "0"**

i don't know what i have to to do.

i am using this code:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#########");
double a = Distancevals[1] * Distancevals[2];
//Distancevals is an array of double with big values
EditText editto = (EditText)findViewById(...);
editto.setText(df.format(a));
```

Comment: why don't you just show it as `editto.setText(a+"");` ? Cause in your case EditText is not doing anything  but DecimalFormat is changing your number.

Comment: thank u for ur comment Frankenstein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Double` stores your number `12345678987654321` in format `1.23456789876543E16`, so you lose the end of the number `21`. When you format the result it's known that your number consists of 17 signs, so `format` function adds two zeros in the end of your number instead of `21`.

Try to use this:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#########");
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(Distancevals[1] * Distancevals[2]);
// Distancevals is an array of double with big values
EditText editto = (EditText) findViewById(...);
editto.setText(df.format(a));
```

Comment: I added solution. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
DecimalFormat df= new DecimalFormat("###############00");
double a=Distancevals[1]*Distancevals[2];
//Distancevals is an array of double with big values
EditText editto=(EditText)findViewById(...);
editto.setText(df.format(a));
```

Comment: thank u shabbir for ur answer. but i think i didn't explain well that problem. see, in my app when i set any double big value on EditText or String or something, if it had over 15 characters my app replace remainig chars with "0" , and i want to correct this bug. for example when my variable has 12345123451234512345 value and i set it on EditText, EditText shows 1234512345123451234500000

i confiused

Comment: double(8 bytes as in java) Covers a range from 4.94065645841246544e-324d to 1.79769313486231570e+308d (positive or negative).Better you use String class for your operations.

Answer (score 0):

You just show it as `editto.setText(a+"");`

Cause in your case EditText is not doing anything but DecimalFormat is changing your number.

Comment: but in this case if my value be a rouand number it will be showd with ".0" at end. for example if a=123 it will be showed like "123.0", its too bad :(

Comment: you tried this code and its giving worng values? you can use `BigDecimal` class instead Decimal

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that in the line:

```
editto.setText(df.format(a));
```

Change it to:

```
editto.setText(df.format(a.toString()));
```